# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I had a warning:WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/Project/testAddUser] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

I can't find where's wrong. I referenced many tutorials and I think my project is properly configured. Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

here's my web.xml file.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml /WEB-INF/hibernateContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value></param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>


  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

here's my applicationContext.xml.
I tried with `<context:component-scan base-package="com.plainart.member.controller" />` but other errors occur. So I make it a comment to get rid of that.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<!-- 
<context:component-scan base-package="com.plainart.member.controller" />
 -->
<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

my controller

```
package com.plainart.member.controller;

import java.util.Map;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import com.plainart.member.model.User;
import com.plainart.member.service.UserService;

@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String listUsers(Map<String,Object> map){
        map.put("user",new User());
        map.put("userList",userService.listUser());
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value ="/")
    public String index(){
        return "index";
    }


    @RequestMapping("/testAddUser")
    public String testAddUser(){
        User testUser = new User();
        testUser.setFirstName("John");
        testUser.setLastName("Smith");
        userService.addUser(testUser);
        return "testUser";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/addUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user")User user,BindingResult result){
        userService.addUser(user);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/deleteUser")
    public String deleteUser(@PathVariable("userId")Integer id){
        userService.removeUser(id);
        return "redirect:/index";
    }
}
```

[my directory tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqhkT.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create dispatcher-servlet.xml file, and put there your controller package.

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.plainart.member.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

Then map it in your web.xml file

```
<context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I think that you have problem with inititalizing your configuration location.
Try it in following way

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml,/WEB-INF/hibernateContext.xml, /WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: thanks for your follow-up. I tried but now it comes with a 404 error. Is that anything wrong with my @RequestMapping ?